# Django Admin Serving Old static design and not new

Tags: django, nginx

I just launched my site and when I go to the Ip address of the site, like the actual 11 integers, I get the new clean look of the admin, but when I go to the actual address like thissite.com/admin/ I get a different design of the admin, that has a much older look. I have collected the static files 
on the server and everything else is being served correctly. I would like to know why this is happening! Thank You!

Comment: Have you tried restarting the Django process on your server and clearing your browser cache?

Comment: @voodoo-burger How do I do that?

Comment: it depends on how you are running the WSGI process. In dev you would just restart `manage.py runserver`. I use Gunicorn to deploy my sites so I restart the instance of Gunicorn that is running that site.